# Am trying to implement Mail reader sampler. But i Am getting the reponse in Folder in the Response data in Jmeter

Tags: email, jmeter, response

I am trying to extract an email using Mail Reader Sampler via Jmeter. But i am getting the response in this manner https://i.stack.imgur.com/xukfC.jpg

I am not understanding why it is happening....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it happens when you switch [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener mode between Text and HTML or XML. The solution is just to restart JMeter or add a new View Results Listener in "Text" mode.

As a workaround you can add Beanshell Listener with the following code:

```
log.info(sampleResult.getResponseDataAsString());
```

This way you will be able to see responses in either *jmeter.log* file or in log window by clicking yellow icon with exclamation sigh in upper-right corner of JMeter main frame:

[image: JMeter response to log]

See [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) for more details on testing outbound and inbound emails with JMeter

Comment: i used a different email now. Gmail is creating folders in the response but zoho email works perfect